# Save data into local database in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, local-database

I created a windows form in visual studio 2019 and l connected it to local database....but when l rebuild the project all the data removed from the database..why??

Comment: We will need some code before we can answer this, preferably a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

As commented on your question, it's not very clear how you are implementing the database.

I'm going assume that by the fact the data is not persisting that you are using a SQL Database file?

[image]

If this is the case then you want to make sure that you are not copying the DB to the output directory every time you build

[image]

If you are looking for data to persist across sessions then it would be better to host a local SQL Server. Check out Tim Corey's guide to SQL Database management and C# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijDcHGxyqE4